# How to convert an image into point data for ggplot2 scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bitmap, scatter-plot

I recently found a [package on Github](https://github.com/shabbychef/SPYvsSPY/blob/master/README.md) where the dev analyzed fan-curated data on the 248 installments of the Spy vs Spy comic by Antonio Prohias appearing in Mad Magazine.

He goes through some basic exploratory data analysis, computes a running net score of Black Spy victories and then runs a non-parametric test (Wald Wolfowitz test) to look at clusters of consecutive victories by one of the Spies in order to ascertain if Prohias kept the score balance by reversing the previous outcome, or if he perhaps picked favorites.

While I found it a fun exercise I was most interested in the Spy Plot.

[image: Spy Vs. Spy]

The point data for the Spy Plot actually came from a [MATLAB easter egg](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/spy-easter-egg-take-2) `spy()` package and the dev put this point data into R as a [tibble::tribble](https://github.com/shabbychef/SPYvsSPY/blob/master/README.Rmd).

My question is how can one create point data from an image? Is it possible to do [edge detection in R with `imager()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imager/vignettes/gettingstarted.html) to get an outline

[image]

And then somehow convert this image data into into a `tbl_df`? I'm unfamiliar with bitmap arrays but perhaps the answer lies in something like this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `imager::cannyEdges` to get the edges, then put the coordinates in a data frame to plot.

```
library('ggplot2')
library('imager')

plot(boats)
```

[image: boats]

```
img <- cannyEdges(boats)
plot(img)
```

[image: edges]

It looks like `img` is a logical array with 4 dimensions.

```
dim(img)
# [1] 256 384   1   3
```

I just want two dimensions, so I'll discard two of the dimensions.

```
img <- img[, , 1, 1]
img[1:8, 1:8]
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]
# [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

`which` can convert this matrix into a list of coordinates.

```
coords <- which(img, arr.ind = T)
head(coords)
#      row col
# [1,] 255   1
# [2,] 255   2
# [3,] 255   3
# [4,] 255   4
# [5,] 255   5
# [6,] 255   6
```

Now it can be plotted.

```
df <- data.frame(x = coords[,1], y = coords[,2])

ggplot(df, aes(x, -y)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]